# Catch event close notification in StandOutWindow android?

Tags: android, switch-statement, toggle

I am using StandOutWindow library.
In my Setting screen,I have a switch (turn on/off). If I turn on switch, a popup and a notification are displayed. 
When I turn off switch, popup isn't display.
I wanna, when I click on notification, popup is hidden and switch has "OFF" status. Now,I only  do popup is hidden. Switch also has "ON" status. How to I can turn off switch.
I tried write code in `getPersistentNotificationIntent` but can not.
Here is my code:

```
public class TogglePopup extends StandOutWindow {
    public View view;

    @Override
    public String getAppName() {
        return "JSDict";
    }

    @Override
    public int getAppIcon() {
        return android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void createAndAttachView(int id, final FrameLayout frame) {
        // create a new layout from body.xml
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_toggle, frame, true);
        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.toggle_popup);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                LinearLayout viewLinear = (LinearLayout) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.toggle_popup_background);

                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    viewLinear
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_toggle_on);

                    ComponentName service = getApplicationContext()
                            .startService(
                                    new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                            ClipboardMonitor.class));
                    StandOutWindow.closeAll(getApplicationContext(),
                            ClipboardMonitor.class);
                    StandOutWindow.show(getApplicationContext(),
                            ClipboardMonitor.class, StandOutWindow.DEFAULT_ID);
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                    viewLinear
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_toggle_off);

                    getApplicationContext().stopService(
                            new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    ClipboardMonitor.class));
                    StandOutWindow.closeAll(getApplicationContext(),
                            ClipboardMonitor.class);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // the window will be centered
    @Override
    public StandOutLayoutParams getParams(int id, Window window) {
        return new StandOutLayoutParams(id, 250, 300,
                StandOutLayoutParams.CENTER, StandOutLayoutParams.CENTER);
    }

    // move the window by dragging the view
    @Override
    public int getFlags(int id) {
        return super.getFlags(id) | StandOutFlags.FLAG_BODY_MOVE_ENABLE
                | StandOutFlags.FLAG_WINDOW_FOCUSABLE_DISABLE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistentNotificationMessage(int id) {
        return "Click to close the JSDict";
    }

    @Override
    public Intent getPersistentNotificationIntent(int id) {
        return StandOutWindow.getCloseIntent(this, TogglePopup.class, id);
        /*
         * StandOutWindow.show(this, WidgetsWindow.class,
         * StandOutWindow.DEFAULT_ID);
         */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a single persistent notification for the StandOut service, or else android will kill your service on low memory (which happens every 5 seconds). You are mistaken about the fact that there is a new persistent notification for each new window. Unless you have multiple types, you will only have one persistent notification no matter how many windows the user opens. If multiple types are an issue, look at FloatingFolders for how to implement multiple types in a single service.